# Application variables Grails 3.2

Tags: grails, web-applications, configuration

I am using Grails 3.2 and I am wondering where I should put my application variables for different enviroments.

`application.yml` or `build.gradle`?

And, how should I define them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put them in the application.yml [as stated in the documents](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/conf.html#config):

> Configuration in Grails is generally split across 2 areas: build
>   configuration and runtime configuration.
>
> Build configuration is
>   generally done via Gradle and the build.gradle file. Runtime
>   configuration is by default specified in YAML in the
>   grails-app/conf/application.yml file.

You can also choose to use the Grails 2.0-style Groovy configuration as mentioned in the next alinea:

> If you prefer to use Grails 2.0-style Groovy configuration then you
>   can create an additional grails-app/conf/application.groovy file to
>   specify configuration using Groovy's ConfigSlurper syntax.

Comment: Just to add a note that you can provide environment specific config files as needed:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/09/grails-goodness-using-external.html

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: http://docs.grails.org/3.2.0/guide/conf.html#environments

> Grails supports the concept of per environment configuration. The application.yml and application.groovy files in the grails-app/conf directory can use per-environment configuration using either YAML or the syntax provided by ConfigSlurper. As an example consider the following default application.yml definition provided by Grails: